# Jasper Subreport Only Populating On First Page - Java

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a main report with a subreport in the group footer. The goal is to show this subreport on every page. In Jaspersoft Studio this works perfectly but when I compile and fill the template in my Spring service, the subreport is only filled on the first page. When I put "All Sections No Detail" for "When No Data Type", I only see the column headers. I have spent hours upon hours trying to debug with no success. Below is the jrxml and java code.

**JRXML**

```
<groupFooter>
    <band height="144">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="70" y="90" width="642" height="30" uuid="47af6568-4e1c-4dc4-8688-dfb4d6e17bbc"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{TEMPLATE_DATA}]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{TEMPLATE_XML}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</groupFooter>
```

**Java Code**

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>()
parameters.add("TEMPLATE_XML", compiledSubReport)

List<entity> entityList = util.getEntities()
JRBeanCollectionDataSource data = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(entityList)

parameters.add("TEMPLATE_DATA", data)

return JasperFillManager.fillReport(mainReport, parameters, mainDataSource)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data source objects cannot be used several times, you need to create a fresh one each time the subreport is displayed.

You can do that by passing `entityList` to the report as a parameter, and then using this for the subreport:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{ENTITY_LIST})]]></dataSourceExpression>
```